# Computing the sum of n number returned by a function, in a different function

Tags: python, database, function, class

I am trying to write a program where users can input information about subjects they have to study and it computes the total amount of time needed for them to study all of their topics. The user can update the information at the end of the day such as how many pages they have left to study and how long they reckon it takes to study one page so the program recalculates how many more hours of study they have left. For that, it asks the user to:

STEP 1. Input the number of pages per subject and how long it will take them to study each page
STEP 2. It then calculates how long it will take to study the subject
 
STEP 3. Calculates the sum of the times required to study all of the subjects
STEP 4. Saves the information to a database
STEP 5. Brings back up all the information when the users asks it (the functions for this part have been excluded in the code below for briefty)

I am stuck at step 3. I cannot get the program to draw on the information that is in step 2 to compute the sum of all the different times required to study each subject as I do not seem to be able to transfer the information from one function to another but cannot figure out what I am missing. Any ideas?

Thank you!

And this is the code:

```
TEXT_FILE_NAME = '/Users/stephanierobinson/Desktop/database.txt'

class StudyHelper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.database_info = self.read_information_from_database()
        self.time_to_study_subject = self.time_to_study_subject

    def save_information_to_database(self, info):
        with open(TEXT_FILE_NAME, 'w') as f:
            f.truncate()
            json.dump(info, f)

    def read_information_from_database(self):
        with open(TEXT_FILE_NAME, 'r') as f:
            database_info = json.loads(f.readline())
            return database_info

    def total_time_to_study(self):
        Final_total=[self]
        sum_time_to_study_subject = (sum(Final_total))
        print("You have %s hours to go before completing your study program" %)

        subject_info = {'Total study time = sum_time_to_study_subject'},
        return subject_info

    def get_subject_info_from_user(self):
       number_of_pages = int(input("Number of pages to study: "))
       average_time_per_page = int(input("Average time per page (in minutes): 
       "))
       time_to_study_subject = number_of_pages * average_time_per_page / 60
       self.Final_total.append(time_to_study_subject)

       print ("It will take you %s hours to complete this subject" 
                %time_to_study_subject)


       subject_info = {'Number of pages to study': number_of_pages,
                       'Average time per page(in hours)': average_time_per_page,
                       'Time to study the subject': time_to_study_subject
                       },

       return subject_info
```

Comment: Some comments throughout the code explaining what it does would be much appreciated. Out of the top of my head, I already want to ask: what's `Final_total`? Why don't your class have an attribute that's a dictionary of `subject_info` with keys being the name of the subject? Or better, why don't you have a `Subject` class that would deal with all that, and that you could then use within your `StudyHelper`? (having a list of `Subject` instances, each holding a name and information about the subject)

Comment: the subjects are unknown, the user inputs them and they need to be able to recall them later on thus why i use a database instead. The names of the functions say what that function does. e.g. total_time_to_study computes the time needed to study

Comment: Unknown subjects doesn't mean you can't have a `Subject` class that will be used to store information about each subject the user inputs. As to comments on your code: even if I know what `total_time_to_study` should return, I have no idea what is the rationale for starting off with `Final_total = [self]`. Also, why is this function returning a dictionary with one key that has no value, anyway? See, this is why you comment a code: to say what each step should do, and then sometimes it helps you see what's wrong about your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your study helper class, define a variable to hold your list.
That should be Final_total.

In total_time_to_study():

```
def total_time_to_study(self):
   Final_total=[self] <---- this is a list with your helper object, not a list of numbers
   sum_time_to_study_subject = (sum(Final_total)) <--- should be sum(self.Final_total)
   print("You have %s hours to go before completing your study program" %)

   subject_info = {'Total study time = sum_time_to_study_subject'},
   return subject_info
```

you should be calculating the sum by using sum(self.Final_total)

You are setting a local variable Final_total to a list that contains the helper object. Which is not correct.

Your print is also wrong because it is missing a variable to print.

```
print("You have %s hours to go before completing your study program" % sum_time_to_study_subject)
```

Comment: You are setting a local variable Final_total to a list that contains the helper object. Which is not correct. --> Can you explain why this is not correct? Would be helpful and appreciated. I am obviously getting it wrong because I don't know what the correct answer is

Comment: You are creating a new list that contains an object of type StudyHelper
`Final_total=[self]`
what you want is to use self.Final_total
`sum_time_to_study_subject = (sum(self.Final_total))`

The reason why yours is wrong is because there is no way to sum the object you have created, you need to sum a list of ints, or floats, or type that supports sum.